# Rotations acting on quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

Suppose I have a free relativistic massive particle described by a state $|p,\sigma\rangle,$, with $p^\mu=(p^0,0,0,p^3)$, so that $P^3|p\rangle=p^3 |p,\sigma\rangle$ and $J_3|p,\sigma\rangle=\sigma|p,\sigma\rangle$, so $\sigma$ is the particles spin along the z-axis.

Now suppose I rotate around the y-axis by an angle $\theta$ so that I now have the state

$$e^{iJ_2\theta}|p,\sigma\rangle$$

If I set $\theta=\pi$ I have the state $e^{iJ_2\pi}|p\rangle$. Classically, if I were to do this I would now expect to find

$$P^3e^{iJ_2\pi}|p,\sigma\rangle=-p^3e^{iJ_2\pi}|p,\sigma\rangle$$

This question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243029/how-is-it-possible-to-change-the-direction-of-a-spin-by-boosting) is very related, but there are some issues there; mostly because $J_3$ doesn't measure spin as the question suggests, it measures angular momentum about the z-axis.

Now, I've used the Poincaré algebra to expand the exponential and move $P^3$ past all copies of $J_2$, but it really doesn't lead anywhere useful. So;

**Question:** Is it wrong to expect $P^3e^{iJ_2\pi}|p,\sigma\rangle=-p^3e^{iJ_2\pi}|p,\sigma\rangle$? I would also expect $J_3e^{iJ_2\pi}|p,\sigma\rangle=-\sigma e^{iJ_2\pi}|p,\sigma\rangle$ but let's try and sort out the momenta first.

The only way I could really see it working is if I could say $e^{iJ_2\pi}=(-1)^{J_2}=-1$ but I don't know how to justify that.

Comment: The rotated state is an eigenstate of $e^{-iJ_2\theta}P_3 e^{iJ_2\theta}$, not of $P_3$. Just visualize a 3d vector $\vec p = (0,0,p)$ subject to a rotation of $\theta$ around the $y$ axis. Along what direction do you expect its magnitude to measure $p$ again? Certainly not along $z$. Same here.

Comment: @udrv For an arbitrary rotation, no, of course not. I'm talking about a rotation by $\pi$.

Comment: Can't write details right now, but use the commutation relations $[P_i, J_j] = i \epsilon_{ijk}P_k$ and the Baker-Cambell-Hausdorff formula for $e^X Y e^{- X}$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula, to show that in general $e^{-iJ_2\theta} P_3 e^{iJ_2 \theta} = P_3 \cos\theta - P_1\sin\theta$, and that in particular it gives $-P_3$ for $\theta = \pi$. The rest is easy algebra.