# Weinberg's definition of a single particle state of momentun $p$ $\Phi_{p,\sigma}$ using a standard momentum $k$ in his QFT book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, momentum

In Weinburg's qft book (chapter 2.5), he uses a standard momentum $k$ and a lorentz transformation L to represent the momentum $p$ of a particle:
\begin{equation}p^{\mu}=L^{\mu }_{\nu}(p)k^{\nu}       \tag{2.5.4}\end{equation}
Then he defines the state of momentum $p$ and other dof $\sigma$ $\Phi_{p,\sigma}$ as:
\begin{equation} \Phi_{p,\sigma} \equiv N(p)U(L(p))\Phi_{k,\sigma}\tag{2.5.5}\end{equation}

My question is, for a fixed k ,p and L, why the non-momentum dof $\sigma$ is the same for both side of equation (2.5.5)?

Besides, Weinburg has a line under (2.5.5): Up to this point, we have said nothing about how the $\sigma$ labels are related for different momenta; Eq.(2.5.5) now fills that gap.

I don't know clearly what this sentence mean, can't we choose $\sigma$ freely here?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240746